# jQuery Mobile breaks Twitter Typeahead.js on page change

Tags: jquery-mobile, typeahead.js

Does anybody know why [Twitter Typeahead.js](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) breaks when changing jQuery Mobile pages?

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/ajkrguns/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="text">
          <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
        </div>
        <a>Go to <a href="#page2">page 2</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div class="text">
          <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA">
        </div>
        <p>Back to <a href="#page1">page 1</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS (from the Typeahead.js demos):

```
$('.search input').each(function() {
  $(this).typeahead({
    hint: true,
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1
  }, {
    name: 'states',
    displayKey: 'value',
    source: substringMatcher(states)
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your code in `pagecreate` to initialize *textinput* within target page `event.target`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (event) {
    $('.typeahead', event.target).typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'states',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ajkrguns/7/)**

Comment: Thanks so much! I had mine wrapped in `pagecontainershow` - which ended up creating two inputs on the 2nd page. I forgot to include that in the fiddle.

Comment: @MarkBoulder you're welcome! Use `pagecreate` or `beforecreate` since they fire once per page ;)